# Convert this C-Code to Delphi-Code

Tags: c, delphi, pointers, casting

I need to convert this C-Code to Delphi-Code and because my Delphi-Knowledge is not good enough I need your help!

My main problem is, that I don't know how to cast pointers / calculate with pointers in Delphi.

Of course i tried to convert it and for whoever is familiar with both languages should this be easy to do :)

Original code (C):

```
void* GetPayloadExportAddr( LPCWSTR lpPath, HMODULE hPayloadBase, LPCSTR lpFunctionName ) {
  // Load payload in our own virtual address space
  HMODULE hLoaded = LoadLibrary( lpPath );

  if( hLoaded == NULL ) {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    void* lpFunc   = GetProcAddress( hLoaded, lpFunctionName );
    DWORD dwOffset = (char*)lpFunc - (char*)hLoaded;

    FreeLibrary( hLoaded );
    return (DWORD)hPayloadBase + dwOffset;
  }
}
```

and

```
BOOL InitPayload( HANDLE hProcess, LPCWSTR lpPath, HMODULE hPayloadBase, HWND hwndDlg ) {
  void* lpInit = GetPayloadExportAddr( lpPath, hPayloadBase, "Init" );
  if( lpInit == NULL ) {
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread( hProcess, NULL, 0,
        lpInit, hwndDlg, 0, NULL );

    if( hThread == NULL ) {
      return FALSE;
    } else {
      CloseHandle( hThread );
    }
  }
```

And the partally converted Delphicode:

```
function GetPayloadExportAddr( lpPath: LPCWSTR; hPayloadBase: HMODULE; lpFunctionName: LPCWSTR) : Pointer;
var
  hLoaded: HMODULE;
  lpFunc: pointer;
  dwOffset: DWORD;
begin
   hLoaded := LoadLibrary( lpPath );

  if( hLoaded = 0 ) then
  begin
    Result := 0;
  end
  else
  begin
    lpFunc   := GetProcAddress( hLoaded, lpFunctionName );
    dwOffset := DWORD(PCHAR(lpFunc) - PCHAR(hLoaded));

    FreeLibrary( hLoaded );
    Result := PDWORD(DWORD(hPayloadBase) + dwOffset);
  end;
end;
```

and

```
procedure CallStopHack( hProcess: THandle; lpPath: LPCWSTR; hPayloadBase: HMODULE);
var
  lpInit : Pointer;
  hThread: THandle;
  bla:Cardinal;
begin
  lpInit := GetPayloadExportAddr(lpPath, hPayloadBase, 'StopSpeedhack');
  if( lpInit = nil ) then
  begin
    Exit;
  end
  else
  begin
     hThread := CreateRemoteThread( hProcess, nil, 0,
        lpInit, 0, 0, bla);

    if( hThread = 0 ) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end
    else
    begin
      CloseHandle( hThread );
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I assume that I messed up with the PDWORD()-Cast etc. I'm sorry but I don't know how to cast it correctly.

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
dwOffset := DWORD(lpFunc) - hLoaded;
```

lpFunc is already a pointer and all you want is the address, hLoaded is already a NativeUint.

and

```
Result := Ptr(hPayloadBase + dwOffset);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems. `LPCWSTR` and `LPCSTR` are not the same. The first translates to `PWideChar`, while the second finally translates to `PAnsiChar` (or `MarshaledAString`, which is the same).

Also, if you are using Delphi 2009 or higher, you should not use `PChar` to cast for pointer math. Use either `PByte` or `PAnsiChar`, as these are single-byte types.

Note, however, that in Delphi, handles are integral types already, so there is no need to cast them at all:

```
dwOffset := NativeUInt(lpFunc) - hLoaded;
```

And later on:

```
Result := Pointer(hPayloadBase + dwOffset);
```

---

Note that I find code that tries to read an offset by subtracting a handle from a pointer (and then uses that offset to add to another handle) rather suspicious. It may work, but it looks like a terrible hack to me.

Comment: It's not suspicious in the slightest. It is explicitly documented than an HMODULE is the base address of the module.

Comment: Handles are supposed to be opaque types. If (it is documented that) you can treat a handle like a pointer, it is not a handle anymore.

Comment: That's a naive view. An `HMODULE` is the base address. That's the beginning and end of it. It uniquely identifies a module because two modules cannot exist at the same address.

Comment: Abstraction is not a naive view at all. Handles are there so that pointers are treated like opaque types, that only have meaning to the implementer.

Comment: Abstraction is indeed not a naive view point. However, treating something that is concrete as if it were abstract is certainly not useful. You need to update your belief as to what an `HMODULE` really is. It is more than you think it is. You can treat it as a unique handle to a module. And you can treat it as the base address of that module.

Comment: Handles ARE meant to be abstract. That, as exception, a HMODULE has a known address is, well, an exception.

Comment: Module handles ARE meant to be concrete. Well, anyway, at least you know that now and can modify the confusing text in your answer.

Comment: What is confusing about it? I still consider it a hack.

Comment: Handles in general are NOT concrete, at least not to their user. They can be anything. That, in this case, we know what the bit pattern stands for is, well, an exception and IMO not something to rely on.

Comment: Oh. So you don't think that a module handle is the base address?!

Comment: I guess that's fundamentally where you are getting confused. You are quite right with all that you say about abstract handles. But an `HMODULE` is not abstract. Everything else will become clear once you understand that. Of course you may well continue to deny this. You can happily do that right up until the point where you need to know the module's base address.

Comment: I KNOW that a HMODULE happens to be the base address, according to MSDN. I still think it is a hack to call something in memory by calculating its address, despite that knowledge. I actually consider it a hack to use a handle as pointer, even if we happen to know some details.

Comment: As I said, that stance is perfectly tenable, right up until the moment when you actually need to obtain a module's base address. And no, you do not KNOW that an HMODULE **happens** to be the base address because that is not true. An HMODULE is by definition the base address. The library provides that as a hard guarantee. Anyway, it's pointless continuing this argument. You have your view, and I have mine.

Comment: I have no problem with applying hacks, when unavoidable, but that does not mean I don't call it a hack and it means that I will always keep in mind it may break big time one day, and/or that I may find a better, non-hackish solution and use that.

Comment: You are simply wrong to regard this as a hack. That's what you cannot seem to understand. Never mind, you aren't going to listen to me are you!

Comment: A HMODULE is by definition a handle (see the corresponding .h file), and that means it is an opaque bit pattern. So no, a HMODULE is not *by definition* the base address. It *happens to be* the base address and that *happens to be* documented.

Comment: You are quite wrong. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#HMODULE It's almost as if you don't want to lose face.

Comment: @david: A handle is a handle, even if it happens to be a base address and no matter if that is documented or not. That has nothing to do with losing face. I had already seen that documentation and I already acknowledged that MSDN says so. I bet that most other (but not all) handles are address to structures too (or nil, or pointers to some offset into a structure), and if they document that that doesn't mean they are not handles anymore. So let's agree that we disagree. Even if we know what a handle points to, I consider it a hack using that knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, but that is simply not true. Doing so is a hack, even if you don't like it.

Comment: The documentation makes it quite clear that an `HMODULE` is the module's base address. If you choose to live in denial of that, I don't care.

Comment: `The documentation makes it quite clear that an HMODULE is the module's base address.` I have acknowledged that a few times already, so you don't have to repeat it. The fact that we know what the bits of a HMODULE mean does not make it any less a handle. What is your problem?

Comment: I have no problem. I understand clearly what an `HMODULE` is. It's the base address of the module. You on the other hand think it is something else.